# Where does the CLion IDE look for header files?

Tags: c++

I'm using the CLion IDE and need to put some OpenGL files in. In the JetBrains/CLion folder there's a bin and lib folder. In the lib folder theres jar files, do I put the header and dlls in here?

get this error:

```
CMakeFiles\GL.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK':
c:/mingw/include/gl/glut.h:486: undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit'
CMakeFiles\GL.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':
c:/mingw/include/gl/glut.h:503: undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit'
CMakeFiles\GL.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':
c:/mingw/include/gl/glut.h:549: undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\GL.dir\build.make:86: recipe for target 'GL.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [GL.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:59: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/GL.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/GL.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/GL.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/GL.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:109: recipe for target 'GL' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [GL] Error 2
```

Comment: (1) you add include paths in [CMakeLists.txt](http://www.cmake.org/documentation/) (2) You should use system OpenGL headers

Comment: (3) It was bad idea to put `glut` headers inside `mingw` include folder. (4) Now you should link glut `.lib`(`.a`) to your program (with CMake)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the FAQ [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/):

> At present CLion supports GCC and Clang compilers and is guided by these two to get the libraries and headers paths.

So it depends on the compiler CLion is using where it looks for the header files.

Comment: CLion uses CMake as a build system, which in turn points out paths for any supported compiler

Comment: It's not finding it. i put the GL section in MiniGW/include

Comment: @emlai I've installed both `Clang` and `GCC` in my MacOS, how can I find which one is it using?

Comment: Does this help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-switch-compilers-in-clion.html